# How to generate a tinyurl in Delphi

Tags: html, delphi, url, delphi-7

I have a chat program, written in Delphi 7,  that I would like to replace long url's posted, with a smaller tinyurl as displayed. I've Googled but haven't found anything helpful quite yet.

Comment: It's kind of annoying when URLs are hidden behind inscrutable shortened versions. In your case, I suggest using shorter text for the *displayed* text, but maintain the original URL for display in the status bar or a hint, just like the Web browsers do it. Let chat recipients see the real URLs that people are posting to them, so they can better judge whether they really want to click. Stack Overflow does that for long URLs in comments, for example.

Answer (score 7):

Try http://www.scripting.com/stories/2007/06/27/tinyurlHasAnApi.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google Shortener API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started).

Using REST you can send a JSON value like this:

```
{"longUrl": "http://stackoverflow.com/"}
```

and the result looks like this:

```
{
"kind": "urlshortener#url",
"id": "http://goo.gl/lgNaMv",
"longUrl": "http://stackoverflow.com/"
}
```

You need implement authentification.
Regards.